# nodejs read session from database

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, node.js, nowjs-sockets

Im writing an application using nodejs, nowjs, codeigniter and mysql. Im using database to store the session. Is there a good way to check and retrieve the session cookie in nodejs? So if that for example, i need to check if a user owns a specific row in the database that is about to get deleted, using nowjs. e.g:

server:

```
//some code here to get session cookie and retrieve stored data from database

var session = { user_id: //userid from database }

everyone.now.deleteGuestbook = function(recordId) {
    var owner_id = client.query(
        'SELECT owner_id FROM guestbook WHERE id = ?',
        [recordId]
    );
    if (session.user_id === owner_id) {
        client.query(
        'DELETE FROM guestbook WHERE id = ?',
        [recordId], function() {
                 everyone.now.deleteRecord;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

client:

```
//Delete guestbook record
$('#guestbook_records li').live('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a.delete')) {
        var id = $(this).find('a.delete').attr('href');
        dialogBox('warning', 'Are you sure you want to delete the record?',
            function() {
                now.deleteGuestbook(id);
            });
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    return false;
});

now.deleteMessage = function(id) {
    $('li[class="' + id + '"]').slideUp(400, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you just looking for code review or is something broken?

Comment: @Raynos Well the question is about how to retrieve cookie data in nodejs actually. Put the code there if there were a specific way to do it considering the code i wrote.

Comment: George, I am in the same situation. Have you found a solution to this problem? I am also looking for a way to pass the value from a session cookie to nodejs. So, how did you manage to solve this issue? Rob Raisch's reply below does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @wenbert look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364642/codeigniter-nodejs-and-nowjs-integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session ids are typically preserved in client cookies which are surfaced in httpServer handlers as request.headers.cookie.

You'd need to know the name of the cookie containing the session id and then:

```
var cookies=(function(str){                     # create hash from cookie string
      var result={};
      str.split(/;\s+/).forEach(function(e){
        var parts=e.split(/=/,2);
        result[parts[0]]=parts[1]||'';
      });
      return result;
    })(request.headers.cookie),
    sessionCookieName='session',                # name of cookie holding session id
    sessionId=cookies[sessionCookieName]||'';   # session id or ''
```

Comment: Hi Rob Raisch, I get an error that says "request is not defined". Any ideas? Like the OP, I am also using nowjs and want to access the session on the server side.

Comment: Wenbert, how is your handler called? Typically, it has two arguments: request and response. However you write your handlers, I would change the reference to "request" in my example to whatever you have named the first arg in your handler function.

Answer (score 1):

Your client code is messy

```
// live is bad and inefficient
$('#guestbook_records li').live('click', function(e) {
    // this kind of check seems horrid
    if ($(e.target).is('a.delete')) {
        // not very optimum to find it. 
        var id = $(this).find('a.delete').attr('href');
        dialogBox('warning', 'Are you sure you want to delete the record?',
            function() {
                now.deleteGuestbook(id);
            });
    }
    else {
        // why return here?
        return;
    }
    // return false should be in if block.
    return false;
});
```

Try this instead

```
$("#guestbook_records li a.delete").click(function(e) {
    var id = this.href;
    dialogBox("warning", "Are you sure you want to delete the record?",
        function() {
             now.deleteGuesBook(id);
        });
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Also `.hasClass` is better

```
now.deleteMessage = function(id) {
    $('li').hasClass(id).slideUp(400, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
};
```