# codeigniter nodejs and nowjs integration

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, node.js, nowjs-sockets

I am trying to integrate nodejs and nowjs with codeigniter framework, As I dont have time to rewrite the whole site I want to check if a user is logged in. I am using ion_auth and I am storing the session in db.

**Client js:**

```
var session_id = $.cookie('sc_session');

$("form").submit(function() {
    now.distributeMessage($("textarea").val(),session_id);
});

now.receiveMessage = function(message){
    $("body").append("<br>" + message);
};
```

**Heres the nodejs server code:**

**EDIT**:**Simplified it a little, and get session cookie from client js**

```
everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(message,session_cookie) {
    exec('php index.php user_session decrypt ' + encodeURIComponent(session_cookie),
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        var parts = stdout.split(';');
        var session_id = parts[1].split(':')[2];
        var query = 'select * from sc_sessions where session_id=' + session_id;
        client.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
            if (results) {
                everyone.now.receiveMessage(str);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**And here is the controller called by nodejs:**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_session extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
        redirect('index');
    }
  }

  public function decrypt($session_id)
  {
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $session_id = urldecode($session_id);
    echo $this->encrypt->decode($session_id);
  }
}
```

It is working and i can log the user_data to the console from the session in database, and it calls the everyone.now.receiveMessage function properly.

I have three questions regarding this:

1) there are rows inserted into the sc_sessions db table with a session_id but with empty user_data, user_agent and ip 0.0.0.0. One row each time the form is submitted.

What is causing this and how do i fix it?

I know that there is a problem with ajaxcalls and codeigniter sessions. See this thread:

Is there a way to see if the request was made with websockets?

2) What is the best way to check if the user is logged in? e.g if statement where you check to see if the query returned anything or is there a better method?

3) Is there a better method of doing this?

Any help appreciated as I am stuck on this.

George

**EDIT**:
Calling the script from commandline caused it to create a new session. Prevent it by extending the session class.

application/libraries/MY_Session.php

```
<?php
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $CI = get_instance();

        if ($CI->input->is_cli_request())
        {
             return;
        }

        parent::__construct();
    }  
}
```

Comment: It might be a better idea to ask over on CI forums. Chances are ten times better at getting a better answer over there.

Comment: @Steven, no need to direct George BACK to CI forums, SO is very good for CI / PHP / etc questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, but lots of overhead to test an answer.

My best guess is CLI doesn't pass environmental variables like user_agent and ip.  Those are handled by apache, and aren't relevant in CLI requests natively.  I'd go by session_id alone if you know it's secure in a node environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the question a little, with less code.  It still inserts one row in sessions table though. Can't get rid of that problem!! Otherwise it works as it should.

Comment: Does your controller still load the session class for a CLI request?  I think you'll have to get smart about the autoloading, as CI probably doesn't think to disable it automatically...

Comment: Is there some way i can make ci not create session cookie when controller is run from CLI? Maybe by extending the session class. The question is where does it get set?

Comment: It worked by extending the Session class like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394225/prevent-cookie-when-running-script-from-cli-in-codeigniter/