# prevent cookie when running script from CLI in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line

Is there a way of preventing session class to set cookie and adding a record in database when calling it from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way I think would be to extend the Session class like this :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Session extends CI_Session
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $CI = get_instance();

        if ($CI->input->is_cli_request())
        {
            return;
        }

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Just place it in the `application/libraries` folder. And with a controller like this :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function no_cli_session()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged', 'yes');
    }
}
```

When you call the function from your browser the session is set and when you call it from cli it is not.